# Styling works on index.php but disappears on single.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to output woocommerce product in single.php. But the styling breaks for some reason that I can't figure out, despite it is working very well on the index page.

Without looping anything from the database, just requiring get_header function and get_footer function

```
function styles_and_scripts(){
  wp_enqueue_style('style', get_stylesheet_uri());
  wp_enqueue_style('bulma', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/assets/css/bulma.css', null, false);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'styles_and_scripts');
```

Bulma navbar remove it's styling. I guess it has something to do with the link.

Comment: Is there any error in browser console?

Answer (score 0):

Check if bootstrap css isn't loading on single.php. It conflicts with Bulma framework.